# Substitute labels of bar plot in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have a pandas dataframe and I'm doing a bar plot over one specific column ("question_1") using:

```
df1.question_1.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
```

This works well. The value_counts() methods returns the following Series:

```
4  30
3  20
5  15
2  10
```

The first column are then used as the labels for the bars and the seconds column are the bar heigths.

Now I have another dataframe df2 with encodings for the values in the question_1 column of the first dataframe df1:

```
ID  value
1   "test1"
2   "test2"
3   "test3"
4   "test4"
5   "test5"
```

Now I would like to use this encoding for the result of value_counts():

```
"test4"  30
"test3"  20
"test5"  15
"test2"  10
```

In the end my goal is to substitute the labels of the bar plot by these encodings (i.e. instead of 4 I would like to have "test4" as the labels). Perhaps this can also be done in an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

You can map your series index that is resulting from value counts to a new index:

s is the result from value_counts:

```
s = pd.Series([30,20,15,10],index=[4,3,5,2])
```

And ploting:

[image]

df2 is your "encoding dataframe":

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],'value':['test1','test2','test3','test4','test5']})
```

Let's map s.index to df2 values using:

```
s.index = s.index.to_series().map(df2.set_index('ID')['value'])
```

And, plot s now.

```
s.plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
```

Output:

[image]